# Can't use UITableViewDataSource with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can't import UITableViewDataSource if i use a custom cell `BaseCell`. Only works with `UITableViewCell` although `BaseCell` is from type `UITableViewCell`

```
import UIKit

class XptoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> BaseCell {
    let cell = BaseCell()
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: you are returning UITableViewCell not Custom class cell.

Comment: @TusharSharma pasted wrong code ;)

Comment: Did you register the cell? Why bypass dequeueing? Is the datasource set? The delegate set?

Comment: The answer below is correct. This was an example, it was all set. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the opposite:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = BaseCell()
    return cell
}
```

But you probably want to use something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BaseCell") as? BaseCell
    return cell!
}
```

Make sure you set "BaseCell" as your cell identifier, as following:
[image: Sample of interface Builder]

If you get a runtime error like "Found nil while unwrapping optional", you need to see BaseCell as the class for your cell, see picture:
[image]